# How to get the last line in source code

Tags: java, eclipse

I wanted to get the last line of a method in source code. For example:

```
line 17. public void method1(){
line 18.   statement1;
line 19.   statement2;
line 20.   statement3;
line 21. }
```

I know how to get the start position of the method with the following code:

```
compilationUnit.getLineNumber(method.getStartPosition())
```

This returns the number 17, now I want to get the last line of the method, which in this case is the number 21. Is there any command to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you have to add method.getLength() to method.getStartPosition() and then calculate line number using compilationUnit.

```
compilationUnit.getLineNumber(method.getStartPosition() + method.getLength())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it incrementally assigning the lenght to the start position:

```
int methodLength = method.getLength();
compilationUnit.getLineNumber(method.getStartPosition() + methodLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try getLength() of class ATSNode. I am not into SDK of Eclipse this but looking at Javadocs it made sense to me.